# Splitting a Project into multiple repos using git subtree

Tags: git, split, git-subtree

I have a large multi-module project that I am trying to split up into multiple GIT repos. I used the following sequence of commands as suggested by [this link](https://lostechies.com/johnteague/2014/04/04/using-git-subtrees-to-split-a-repository).

```
# Preparing the Split Temp Branch
cd modules\bigproject
git subtree split -P "bigproject.core" -b "subtree-bigproject-core" #rejoin wasn't used

# Pushing into a Bare Repo for the split subtree
git branch --track subtree-bigproject-core origin/subtree-bigproject-core
git push --all origin
mkdir ..\subtree-bigproject-core
cd ..\subtree-bigproject-core
git init --bare
cd ..\bigproject
git push ..\subtree-bigproject-core subtree-bigproject-core:master

# Pushing the subtree repo to remote
cd ..\subtree-bigproject-core
git remote add origin git@ssh-git-xxx.domain.com:grp/module-bigproject-core.git
git push --all origin

# Back into the main repo, including the subtree using `subtree add`
cd ..\bigproject
git rm -r "bigproject.core"
git add -A && git commit -am "replacing bigproject.core with subtree"

git subtree add -P "bigproject.core" --squash \
    -m "adding bigproject.core repo as subtree" \
    git@ssh-git-xxx.domain.com:grp/module-bigproject-core.git master

# Adding subtree remote repo to allow subtree push/pull/merge
git remote add subtree-bigproject-core \
    git@ssh-git-xxx.domain.com:grp/module-bigproject-core.git
```

**Please note that I did *not* use "--rejoin" during the split command execution**

Now I am able to make changes to the main project as well as to the core subtree independently.

However, when I try to push changes from the container "bigproject", for the subtree, by executing the following `git subtree push` command, it starts reading the whole commit history of the main container again, without recognizing that the subtree was actually created from the history of that very container and then added back in using "add".

```
git subtree push -P "bigproject.core" subtree-bigproject-core/master
```

[Roger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12819896/40498) suggests that a "pull"/"merge" is necessary after adding the subtree, but that did not work either. The `git subtree` documentation seems to suggest that `git subtree split --rejoin` is required even after doing a `add`, but when I execute a `subtree split --rejoin` again for that prefix, it starts reading the whole commit history again. With over 10K commits in my repo history, the split is very time taking, and I would like to leverage on the ability of subtree commands to move forward from the point of split.

What am I missing? After adding the "bigproject.core" subtree back into the container repo, I need the ability to:

1. Push changes from the container into the subtree repo.
2. Pull changes from the remote subtree repo into the container. I would be OK to squash these changes in, as long as the changes recognize that the subtree has already been squashed during a previous "subtree add" or "subtree pull" of this subtree.

**Update**: The subtree documentation was confusing to me. The example did not cover my exact scenario and I was not able to make it work for the case described above.

1. It says that --onto is not required if one has used add, and that if add was used, the intelligent merges from the subtree will happen successfully after that. But in my case, the "add" does not seem to have that effect of recognizing that the subtree was created from the original big repo in the first place.
2. It says that the --squash is used, --rejoin is not recommended. Does it mean that if "--squash" is used during "add", one will not be able to leverage on intelligent history reconstruction for subsequent pull/push/merge of subtree?